# Soap client request in Php with CURL not working

Tags: php, curl, soap

How can I create php soap request to look like this. I am unable to get the response in Php curl. But fiddler web debugger is working really well with the code.

Here is the raw request:

POST http://195.230.180.189:8280/services/TopupService?wsdl HTTP/0.9
Host: 195.230.180.189:8280
Content-Length: 691

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:top="http://www.inew-cs.com/mvno/integration/TopupService/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
     <top:TopupRequest>
      <amount>1</amount>
      <amountUnitRelation>1</amountUnitRelation>
      <subscriber>
       <msisdn>8801701340002</msisdn>
      </subscriber>
      <source>
       <distributorId>PayWell</distributorId>
      </source>
      <referenceId>12345</referenceId>
      <transactionId>09876543</transactionId>
     </top:TopupRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

In Php curl request:

```
$url="http://195.230.180.189:8280/services/TopupService?wsdl"; 
   $xml='<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:top="http://www.inew-cs.com/mvno/integration/TopupService/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
        <top:TopupRequest>
         <amount>1</amount>
         <amountUnitRelation>1</amountUnitRelation>
         <subscriber>
          <msisdn>8801701340002</msisdn>
         </subscriber>
         <source>
          <distributorId>100</distributorId>
         </source>
         <referenceId>12345</referenceId>
         <transactionId>09876543</transactionId>
        </top:TopupRequest>
       </soapenv:Body>
         </soapenv:Envelope>'; 
   $headers = array(
       "Content-type: text/xml",
       "Content-length: " . strlen($xml),
       "Connection: close"
      );
     $ch = curl_init(); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

     echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
     if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
     {
      echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
     }
     else
     {
      //echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
     }
     // Close handle
     curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Answer (score 1):

You should not post to that URL. That is not a service endpoint, it is the WSDL, which defines the provided operations.

PHP SoapClient class allows you to build soap requests easily:

```
$wsdl = 'http://195.230.180.189:8280/services/TopupService?wsdl';

$options = [
    'trace' => true,
    'cache' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'exceptions' => true
];

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

$payload = [
    'amount' => 1,
    'amountUnitRelation' => 1,
    'subscriber' => [
        'msisdn' => '8801701340002'
    ],
    'source' => [
        'distributorId' => 'PayWell'
    ],
    'referenceId' => '12345',
    'transactionId' => '09876543',
];

$response = $client->topup($payload);
```

After parsing the given wsdl, the `$client` now has the method `topup`, as defined by `<wsdl:operation>`.

Comment: Did you mean that to try this way
       $options = array(
        'trace' => true,
        'cache' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'exceptions' => true
       );
       $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

       $payload = array(
        'amount' => 1,
        'amountUnitRelation' => 1,
        'subscriber' => array(
         'msisdn' => '8801701340002'
        ),
        'source' => array(
         'distributorId' => 'PayWell'
        ),
        'referenceId' => '12345',
        'transactionId' => '09876543'
       );
       print $response = $client->topup($payload);

Comment: I tried your suggested way but not worked. When I tried the above mentioned way then got Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in /var/www/html/pwl/paywell_crons/gp_plus_api_test.php:142 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('__call('topup', Array) #2 /var/www/html/pwl/paywell_crons/gp_plus_api_test.php(142): SoapClient->topup(Array) #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/pwl/paywell_crons/gp_plus_api_test.php